# facebook login not give me any reson , true or false

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

i want to use the facebook sdk, i make exactly as describe here 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

now i want to login , i used this code

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (session.isOpened()) {

            // make request to the /me API
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                    new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        EditCustomerProfile.this,
                                        user.getName(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.e("facebook-",
                                        user.getName());
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        EditCustomerProfile.this,
                                        "NULLnnl",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.e("facebook", "null");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }else{
            Log.e("session", "not open");
        }
    }
});
```

the problem is that there is no `log`  i mean no if statement and no else statement .

please help

#### Edit

what i added

```
else{
                    Log.e("session", "not open");
                }
```

to check if the session is open, the `log` shows `not open`

Comment: it might be that you are already logged in Facebook on the Emulator or Your test device. Please Sign-out and then Run your Application.

Comment: Don't you forgot about onActivityResult?

Comment: @Geralt_Encore  i don't use onactivity result, should i ? also i edit the question please check it again, and should i sign out from my android facebook ?

Comment: @SAURABH_12 should i signout from the facebook from chrome and mobile ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli you have to use it. This is definitely reason of your problem

Comment: @Geralt_Encore i use it and IT WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOORRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKk write an answer to accept it

Comment: from both chrome and mobile Facebook App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```